# TouchScreenKeyboardUnity doesn't open in Android Phone but works well on iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard

TouchScreenKeyboardUnity doesn't open in Android Phone but works well on iOS.
I'm not using either of GUI.TextField, GUI.TextArea or GUI.PasswordField. I'm trying to open keyboard on button click, but in vain. 
Android Version : 5.0, 5.1

Comment: could you provide your code

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Sorry for Late Reply!

void ButtonPressed(UIButton sender)
 {  
  TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;  
  if (keyboard == null || !TouchScreenKeyboard.visible) 
  {
   keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open ("",    TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false);
  }  
  keyboard.text = playername;
  keyboard.active = true;
 }